Jetpack Compose `BasicTextField2` did not clear focus automatically when keyboard was hide
As the title, here is a BasicTextField2, render as below. when i click close icon on keyboard key and will hide the keyboard, but focus still in BasicTextField2 and could not show keyboard when click textfield to re-edit.
        BasicTextField2(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1.0f),
            state = textFieldState,
            decorator = @Composable {
                val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
                OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.DecorationBox(
                    value = textFieldState.text.toString(),
                    innerTextField = it,
                    enabled = true,
                    singleLine = false,
                    visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
                    interactionSource = interactionSource,
                    container = {
                        OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.ContainerBox(
                            enabled = true,
                            isError = false,
                            interactionSource = interactionSource,
                            colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(),
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(26.dp)
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
        )

i try add focus requester and add log in onFocusChanged, only log the first time i click TextField to edit.
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
BasicTextField2(
   modifier = Modifier
   .weight(1.0f)
   .focusRequester(focusRequester)
   .onFocusChanged {
       println("==== hasFocus: ${it.hasFocus}")
   },
...
)

i saw here is line of source code val isFocused = interactionSource.collectIsFocusedAsState().value
BTW, i also know some ways to fix with LocalFocusManager,
But i would like to find a simple way to bind focus state and keyboard.
